# When to prefix the resource with "api://" when acquiring an AccessToken to gain access to a protected API

Tags: scope, azure-active-directory, access-token

There are two Application Registrations in Azure and both have the `Application ID URI` set to `api://{GUID}`.

However for the first application I need to provide the complete `Application ID URI`, including the prefix `api://`.
And for the second application, I only need to provide the `{GUID}` to get a working valid AccessToken.

Both applications are used on-behalf "access_as_user" scope.

What could be the difference ?

Comment: Any update this issue?

Answer (score 1):

When you set the `Application ID URI` in the portal -> your `App registration` -> `Expose an API`, it will give you a value with format `api://{GUID}` by default, actually the `{GUID}` is the `Application ID`(i.e. `Client ID`) of the AD App.

[image]

[image]

To get the access token for an AAD protected API, providing the `Application ID URI` or `Application ID` for the resource will both work, in your case, make sure you have not changed the `{GUID}` manually i.e. make sure the `{GUID}` is the `Application ID`.